# mingw gdb 64 bit build

Tags: gdb, 64-bit, mingw

I am cross building 32 bit and 64 bit windows target versions of my software on a linux host

when it comes to the inevitable windows specific debugging, I run gdb from within a windows VM.

This works fine for my 32 bit builds, but no good for 64 bit

I have scoured the interwebs but cannot find a 64 bit build version of mingw to give me the 64 bit gdb i desperately need (I have an issue where the 32 bit windows build works but the 64 bit does not and need to be able to get in there with gdb and find out why)

Am I missing something, or is 64 bit pre-built windows stuff just not available for download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mingw-w64 project allows compiling both 32-bit and 64-bit binaries. The Downloads section on the [mingw-w64 website](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net) contains links to various pre-built binaries.

Comment: yes you're right, mingw-w64 provided the answer. Originally I was trying to download from a browser on a linux host and I wasn't seeing the windows binaries, when I had a go from a browser running in my windows VM I found what I needed no problem. Now have a 64 bit version of gdb that I have used successfully against a 64 bit build